# Does WordPress Allow Blank/Empty Comment Submissions In WordPress?

Tags: comments, customization, comment-form

I've got a great Comment Form and Threaded Comments setup by using the native WordPress functions: `comment_form` and `wp_list_comments`.

However, I'm trying to also create a custom Contest Comment template for certain posts. I call `comments_template('/contest-comments.php', true);` conditionally based on whether a certain custom field exists or not. It works great.

I'm trying to make it look along the lines of http://2010.sf.wordcamp.org/attendees/

I only want to show the person's name wrapped in a link and their avatar. Therefore, I want my comment form to only show the Name, Email, and URL fields. The text area should be hidden.

For the Comment Form, I am passing an empty value for the `comment_field` key in the `$args` array I'm passing into `comment_form`.

This makes the comment form look okay, but when someone submits a comment, they get a warning from WordPress saying that their message was blank.

Any solutions on how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: It doesn't, but you can get around this:

```
add_filter('comment_form_field_comment', 'my_comment_form_field_comment');
function my_comment_form_field_comment($default){
  return false;
}

add_action('pre_comment_on_post', 'my_pre_comment_on_post');
function my_pre_comment_on_post($post_id){
  $some_random_value = rand(0, 384534);
  $_POST['comment'] = "Default comment. Some random value to avoid duplicate comment warning: {$some_random_value}";
}
```

If you want this only for certain pages, then you should create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates), for eg "boo.php", and in the code I posted above, only add these filters if the current page template is boo (use `$post->page_template` to get the current page template when doing the check).

Related questions:

- [Removing the "Website" Field from Comments and Replies?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/removing-the-website-field-from-comments-and-replies)
- [Comment form validation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/comment-form-validation)

Comment: I intend to use this on a universal `single.php` file with a custom comment template. I'm a bit confused as to why I would need a custom page template.

Comment: you don't, if you want that textarea disabled trough the entire site.

Comment: I got it working, I just found another trick to solve the issue. I turned what would be normally the text area into a hidden field with a value that includes the time, article title, and post ID. That avoid the duplicate warning issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, use the allow_empty_comment hook, see details here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/allow_empty_comment/

Here is a sample:

```
// Enable empty comment.
add_filter( 'allow_empty_comment', '__return_true' );
```

You may also consider unchecking the checkbox in Settings > Discussion for:

> Comment author must fill out name and email