# How to remove commenters ability to add hyperlinks to comments?

Tags: comments, wysiwyg, filters

I'd like to be able to filter out a commenters ability to add hyperlinks in their comment text.

I removed the "websites" field from the mix to reduce the amount of spammage already (see: [Removing the "Website" Field from Comments and Replies?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/removing-the-website-field-from-comments-and-replies)") which has helped a lot.

By default, they can use the '< a '> tag to do so in the comment box text, which allows spammers to embed hyperlinks to their sites.

Is there a way to filter out that capability in the wysiwyg editor for comment fields?

Comment: nice idea, p.s.: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WP runs so many prettifying filters on this stuff that it's easy to get lost.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
remove_filter('comment_text', 'make_clickable', 9);
add_filter('pre_comment_content', 'strip_comment_links');

function strip_comment_links($content) {

    global $allowedtags;

    $tags = $allowedtags;
    unset($tags['a']);
    $content = addslashes(wp_kses(stripslashes($content), $tags));

    return $content;
}
```

This scrubs out clearly defined links and removes filter that turns plain text links into properly tagged ones.

Comment: This seems to have worked just fine. Added it as a plugin and tested it - life is good! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution -

The function that will remove all `<a>...</a>` from a text (Probably it's better to use strip_tags instead of regex here):

```
     function strip_links($content){
       return preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/iU','', $content);
     }
```

Remove links from all new comments **permanently**, before they are insterted in the db:

```
     add_filter('preprocess_comment', 'new_comment_strip_links');
     function new_comment_strip_links($commentdata){
       $commentdata['comment_content'] = strip_links($commentdata['comment_content']);
       return $commentdata;
     }
```

Or, remove links before we output them to the screen (Your theme should run the 'comment_text' filter somewhere in a template file):

```
     add_filter('comment_text', 'display_comment_strip_links');
     function display_comment_strip_links($content){
       return strip_links($content);
     }
```

Comment: `strip_tags()` is overkill, there are quite a few harmless tags that are allowed in comments for formatting.

Comment: No need for this at all, Rarst's approach using the allowedtags array is better suited here and it's exactly why the array of allowed tags is hookable/definable. Nice shot at a solution nonetheless... :)